# Output array as a "String" separated by commas in c

Tags: c, arrays, output

I have the following array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main () {

int openedLockers[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};


return 0;
}
```

And would like to output "Opened Lockers: 0,1,2,3,4."

It specifically has to end with a period after the last number. I'm not sure how to do this in a for loop in a way that I do not have to print the "Opened Lockers: " part more than once.

Comment: Print the `"Opened Lockers: "` part **before** you enter the loop....

Comment: For future reference, I suspect (strongly) the downvotes you received were due to the missing effort showing what you have tried and where you were stuck. I'm not one that dings new users for that, but rather tries to steer them to read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If followed, and if you search here for duplicates first, that will eliminate downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

int openedLockers[] = {0,1,2,3,4};

printf("Opened Lockers: ");

for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d", openedLockers[i]);

    if (i != 4)
        printf(",");
    else
        printf(".");
}
return 0;
}


// Output : Opened Lockers: 0,1,2,3,4.
```

Comment: Worth a tick for the effort, but you should make it `int openedLockers[] = ...` to avoid the potential error if you add more values than declared elements. No need for `stdlib.h` or `stdbool.h`.

Comment: In my case the last number of the array is unknown but its a simple change from this code thank you.

Comment: There is always at least a dozen ways to skin any one cat in C `:)`

Comment: `i` should be of type `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

A super easy way to achieve the desired format is to use a conditional (ternary) operator as part of your `printf` format string within the output loop, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int openedLockers[] = {0,1,2,3,4},
        n = sizeof openedLockers / sizeof *openedLockers;

    fputs ("Opened Lockers: ", stdout);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (i ? ",%d" : "%d", openedLockers[i]);
    puts (".");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/openlockers
Opened Lockers: 0,1,2,3,4.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: `i` and `n` should be of type `size_t`, `n` most likely `const`-qualified.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but rather than add that to the discussion and with the value limited to `5`, we left it all `int` here `:)` And while you could `const` qualify `n`, it would be rather difficult to `const` qualify `i`.

Answer (score 1):

To do that without branches:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int openedLockers[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    size_t const n = sizeof openedLockers / sizeof *openedLockers;

    printf("Opened Lockers: ");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d,", openedLockers[i]);

    puts("\b."); // overwrite the last comma with a period and add a newline.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int openedLockers[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int const n = sizeof openedLockers / sizeof *openedLockers;

    printf("Opened Lockers: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d,", openedLockers[i]);

    printf("\b.");
}
```

Comment: What do you include `<stddef.h>` for?

Answer (score 0):

Loop only the repeated part to avoid `if`s or other conditional constructs. Note that the repeated part repeats one less time than the number of elements.

```
// before repeats, include first element
printf("Opened Lockers: %d", openedLockers[0]);

// repeat comma, space, element
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    printf(", %d", openedLockers[i]);
}

// after repeats
printf(".\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int *a, int n);
int main(void)
{
    int array[5];

    array[0] = 98;
    array[1] = 402;
    array[2] = -198;
    array[3] = 298;
    array[4] = -1024;
    print_array(array, 5);
    return 0;
}
void print_array(int *a, int n){
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++){
        printf("%d ,",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: "It specifically has to end with a period after the last number. "